# Error At running docker-compose "': No such file or directory't execute 'sh"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

I've a problem with docker container, I'm 100% sure the container works because it worked for my colleagues. I think it's more a configuration problem in my terminal after a lot of search I posted this question.

when i run this command for starting the project

```
docker-compose up rails
```

The answer is always

```
 ': No such file or directory't execute 'sh
```

and here is a part of compose.yml

```
services:
  rails:
    build: .
    image: eu.gcr.io/someone/rails:latest
    command: "bin/rails s -p 3000 -b 0.0.0.0"
    depends_on:
      - mysql
      - mongodb
      - redis
      - nginx
      #- elasticsearch
    environment:
      - MALLOC_ARENA_MAX=2
    env_file:
      - .dockerenv
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src
      - ./ged:/usr/src/ged
      - gems:/usr/local/bundle
    user: "${CURRENT_USER}"
    ports:
      - 3040:3000
      - 3035:3035
```

I tried a lot of solutions but nothing worked, i hope someone has a solution

Comment: Are you trying to run a script somewhere that has DOS line endings?  Does your image declare an ENTRYPOINT?  Does deleting the `volumes:` make a difference?

Answer (score 1):

Finally the solution was to convert file into unix format with the command:

```
dos2unix filename
```

if you have a lot of shell files you can use this command to convert all file in a row

```
find /path -type f -print0 | xargs -0 dos2unix --
```

you will need to install this command with

```
sudo apt install dos2unix
```

Comment: Alternative is to try converting this using the following website.
https://www.fileformat.info/convert/text/dos2unix.tr